# PropertyAccessException while persisting Many to Many relationship

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm running into below exception while trying to persist Many-to-Many relationship. Any clues would be really appreciated. I'm using hibernate's @ManyToMany annotation as shown below.

If I remove houses from the construction entity and then persist it works ok. The problem occurs only when I say construction.setHouses(houses) before calling persist. And I have 3 tables: Construction, House, and Construction_houses. Where Construction_houses stores mapping between construction and house using their primary keys.

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="construction_houses",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="construction_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="house_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private List<House> houses = new ArrayList<>();
```

Exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.construction.domain.House.id
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.construction.domain.House.id
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.construction.domain.BaseEntity.persist(BaseEntity.java:44)
    at com.construction.service.QuizEngineService.generateQuiz(QuizEngineService.java:83)
    at com.construction.service.QuizEngineService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e2bbd45a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:267)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.construction.service.QuizEngineService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4b29f50c.generateQuiz(<generated>)
    at com.construction.service.QuizEngineServiceTest.testQuizEngineServiceMustNotBeNull(QuizEngineServiceTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: could not get a field value by reflection getter of com.construction.domain.House.id
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4746)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4465)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:511)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.construction.domain.House.id to [Ljava.lang.Object;
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.property.DirectPropertyAccessor$DirectGetter.get(DirectPropertyAccessor.java:57)
    ... 96 more
```

House.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "houses")
public class House {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "house_sequence", sequenceName = "house_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "house_sequence")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Construction.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "constructions")
public class Construction {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "construction_sequence", sequenceName = "construction_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "construction_sequence")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "is_completed")
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private boolean isCompleted;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="construction_houses",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="construction_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="house_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<House> houses = new ArrayList<>();

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isCompleted() {
        return isCompleted;
    }

    public void setCompleted(boolean isCompleted) {
        this.isCompleted = isCompleted;
    }

    public List<House> getHouses() {
        return houses;
    }

    public void setHouses(List<House> houses) {
        this.houses = houses;
    }
}
```

Comment: You will need to post the code for House.

Comment: @AlanHay i have pasted the House.java class.

Comment: @AlanHay the code for Construction class is also available. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace states:

> Can not set java.lang.Long field com.construction.domain.House.id to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Unfortunately that message is not only given for setters, but for getters as well.

So the message tells you that it tries to read the field `House.id` not for an object of type House, but for an object of type `Object[]`.

It seems that your `houses` is not a list of `House` objects, but of arrays - or it contains at least one such array.

If you call `System.out.println(construction.getHouses());` right before you persist your construction you will find something like: ...`[Ljava.lang.Object;@`...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The houses is an ArrayList. It does not contain any other array as shown in the class.

Comment: Ok i found what the problem is but don't know how to fix it. The problem is the houses i assign to Construction object already exists in database. i create houses before i persist construction object. i then retrieve houses form db and assign it to construction object and call persist on construction. that seems to be the problem. it don't seem to like that. How can i persist construction object with existing houses?

Comment: Could you add your code where you retrieve your houses and add them to the list?

Comment: As pointed out by Tobias the houses in fact was coming out as an array and not a list. after fixing the code it works now. Thanks a lot guys.